# JS regexp for PO Box

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using javascript to catch any PO box expressions in my address field.
My regexp looks like this right now:

```
var pattern = /(p[-. ]?o.?[- ]? )b(.|ox)/i;
```

The problem is that it will not catch the following expressions:

```
P. O. Box
```

but will catch:

```
P.O. Box
```

How can I modify my code so that it will catch an expression with a space between `P` and `O`, and still catch `po box`?

Comment: Instead of `[-. ]` which means "one of the following: space, dot, dash" use `([-. ]( ?))` which means the same as above followed by a space optionally. If you don't want to match two spaces between P and O you can use `(( )|([-.]( ?))` which means a space _or_ a dot or a dash optionally followed by a space.

Comment: oh thanks, this works perfectly
gotta learn my regex, never used it before )

Comment: What about "Box 230", "P.O.B. 29A" or "Boîte Postale 29-40"? You're making an extraordinary number of assumptions about how these are formatted. If you captured it in a separate field you'd be safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   [Pp]\.(|\s*)[Oo].(|\s*)box
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/inu459fI3KNbSJ5G)

I couldn't get the case insensitive to work for some reason on my machine... However, it'll prob work  perfectly on yours.

```
[Pp]\.(|\s*)[Oo].(|\s*)[Bb][Oo][Xx]
```

heres one that works without the /i

Comment: @Nir Yeah the site is awesome! I use it literally all the time. Hopefully the answer provided works for you!

Answer (score 1):

use following regexp

```
var pattern = /(p[-. ]?\s*o.?[- ]? )b(.|ox)/i;
```

I just added `\s` before `O`.

Comment: I think OP wants the regex to catch both with and without space, so I would use `\s*`.